# How was the band America chosen to provide the music for The Last Unicorn?

Tags: music, the-last-unicorn

Most of the songs (all those not sung by specific characters) for the 1982 Rankin/Bass cartoon of *[The Last Unicorn](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084237/)* were performed by the band [America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_(band)).  America had been quite popular in the early and mid-1970s, but by 1982 their heyday had passed.  During this period, the Rankin/Bass productions seemed to try to get top-quality (although sometimes lesser known, and thus less expensive) talent for their animated musicals.  For example, Glenn Yarbrough's songs for *The Hobbit* (and *The Return of the King*) are generally well regarded; Yarbrough was also, like America, past the peak of his career (which had been in the 1960s with [The Limelighters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Limeliters)).  The title sequence of *The Last Unicorn* was also clearly something that the producers had put significant effort into—with the images being based on the late medieval [La Chasse a la Licorne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunt_of_the_Unicorn) tapestries.

So I was wondering if there was any information about how the producers had selected America to perform the songs (which were composed by [Jimmy Webb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Webb)—who is best known for written "Witchita Lineman" for Glen Campbell) in *The Last Unicorn*.

(What actually caused me to wonder about this was noticing that America's signature song—probably their best known work today by far a wide margin—was the oddly appropriately titled "A Horse with No Name."  It's probably a coincidence, but I think it would be fascinating if this had something to do with the band being selected for *The Last Unicorn*.)

Comment: "by 1982 their heyday had passed" — get 'em for cheap innit.

Comment: "top-quality (although sometimes lesser known, and thus _less expensive_)" I think you answered your own question right there... (as Paul mentioned)